# Hubble tension and density parameter

Tags: cosmology, density

Hi I was reading about the Hubble tension. I know that the Planck Collaboration gives an actual value for the Hubble parameter as $H_{0}=64.3 kms^{-1}Mpc^{-1}$ and the group that measures $H_{0}$ with Type Ia Supernovae gives $H_{0}=74.03 kms^{-1}Mpc^{-1}$.

Since there is a tension for the measured values of $H_{0}$ and since in the standard cosmological model $H_{0}$ is given by

$$H_{0}=\int_{0}^{Z_{last}}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{\Omega_{m}(1+z)^3+\Omega_{r}(1+z)^4+\Omega_{\Lambda}}}$$
where $Z_{last}\approx 1100$ is the redshift where radiation decouples from matter.

Planck Colaboration gives $\Omega_{m}=0.315\pm 0.007$ $\Omega_{\Lambda}=0.6847\pm 0.0073$, $\Omega_{r}= 9.28656\times 10^{-5}$.

And I can't find the values measured with supernovae, but my question is there is a tension between the values of $\Omega$ with CMB and the values with supernovae?

Or someone knows where are the values of $\Omega$ measured with supernovae?

Comment: If you read 24.3.2 'Supernovae as cosmological probes' of the cosmological parameters at PDG http://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/contents_sports.html then you will see some results e.g. 207 DES SNe Ia combined with 122
low-redshift SNe Ω=0.331 ± 0.038

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being model-independent, other than assuming $\Omega_k=0$ (zero curvature of the universe), supernovae measurement of $H_0$ does not need the input of $\Omega_m$, $\Omega_r$, or $\Omega_{\Lambda}$.

Supernovae methods directly measure $H_0$
$$
H_0 = \frac{\dot{a}(t)}{a(t)}|_{t=t_0}
$$
via (see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.01424))

- Red shift to infer the speed of the receding supernovae-hosting
  galaxies
- Cosmic ladders like Cepheids to infer distance

On the other hand, $H_0$ from Planck is model dependent, since it needs the input of $\Omega_m$, $\Omega_r$, and $\Omega_{\Lambda}$ at red shift $z\sim 1100$ to derive the Hubble parameter at red shift $z=0$ by integrating the Friedmann equation all the way from $z\sim 1100$ to $z=0$ as shown above in the OP.

Generally speaking, direct measurements are more trustworthy. Supernovae measurements are actually corroborated by other direct measurement methods (see [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1907.10625), [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.06547), [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.11044), and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.06044)). Barring systemic bias, the culprit and the root cause of "Hubble tension" is most likely the standard cosmology model $\Lambda$CDM (see [Is standard cosmology $\Lambda$CDM currently in deep trouble?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/531836/is-standard-cosmology-lambdacdm-currently-in-deep-trouble)).  Either

- $\Omega_m$, $\Omega_r$, or $\Omega_{\Lambda}$ is possibly off, they are not what we think they are. To quote Donald (another Donald) "there are known knowns...there are known unknowns...there are also unknown unknowns". One might consider adding more "dark" elements into the mixture like the Kafkaesque scenario of "dark interaction between dark matter and dark energy" (I am not making this up. See [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.08821)).
- or there is something wrong with Friedmann equation and for that matter Einstein's gravity equations.

The Jury is still out. And it's an opportune time to be a cosmologist now, since historically "cloud over physics" is a harbinger of phenomenal science breakthroughs.

__

Added note:

There is an interesting Youtube video on the "The crisis in cosmology" (see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EyJHYyRjg14)).

Comment: Do any of these models consider the possibility that time may have been running slower (from our point of view) when the universe was more dense?

Comment: When you do cosmology, you usually choose time in your equations so that the universe looks homogeneous and isotropic at all times. (This time it is known as cosmic time). Some theories modified the statement of anisotropy of the statement of homogeneity (Cosmological Bianchi Models). But I don't  any theory that modifies the time.

Comment: @R.W Bird re time running slower, some claims discussed here  https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/senovillas-slowing-time-theory.206075/

Comment: I think there's some confusion (possible) here. Type Ia supernovae *can* be used to infer cosmological parameters and of course that is what the Nobel prize in Physics was awarded for - the determination of $\Lambda$ using type Ia supernovae. You need to make the distinction between low redshift SNe and SNe at redshifts of 0.5+ which definitely are sensitive to the cosmological parameters.

Comment: @Rob Jeffries. As mentioned in the main answer, the direct measurement of $H_0$ (and for that matter, deceleration parameter $q_0$) is trustworthy. Therefore, one is not challenging "accelerated expansion" of the cosmos. On the other hand, combining "datasets from direct observation at different redshifts" with ΛCDM to infer other cosmological parameters  leads to a lot of troubles:

Comment: (arxiv.org/abs/2002.06044): "We consider a low redshift (z<0.7) cosmological dataset comprising megamasers, cosmic chronometers, type Ia SNe and BAO, which we bin according to their redshift. For each bin, we read the value of H0 by fitting directly to the flat ΛCDM model. Doing so, we find that H0 descends with redshift, allowing one to fit a line with a \textit{non-zero} slope of statistical significance 2.1σ. Our results are in accord with a similar descending trend reported by the H0LiCOW collaboration. "

Comment: Not sure what your last comment is about. That paper assumes a flat $\Lambda$CDM model and has $\Omega_m$ $(=1-\Omega_\Lambda)$ as a free parameter in addition to $H_0$.

Comment: @RobJeffries, yes you are right that the paper assumes a flat $\Lambda$CDM model and using datasets from different redshift to fit free parameters like $\Omega$ and $H_0$ as you mentioned. The shocking fact is that different redshift data yield statistically significant different parameters, which is hard to be explained in the usual $\Lambda$CDM framework.

Comment: I'm not arguing about that. It is your first sentence that is currently misleading.

Comment: @RobJeffries, please specify which part of the first sentence is misleading.

Comment: You have just pointed me to a paper that needs to assume a flat universe and fit a value of $\Omega_M$ at the same time as estimating $H_0$. Getting $H_0$ from anything but very low redshift SNe is not model independent.

Comment: @RobJeffries, please quote exactly which part of my first sentence is misleading, thanks! I mean please use exact quote and be specific.

Comment: "Being model-independent, ...supernovae measurement of H0 does not need the input of Ωm, Ωr, or ΩΛ."

Comment: There is a difference between model insensitive and model-independent. The Riess paper you cite uses low redshift supernova. You can get away with fitting $H_0$ using the deceleration parameter determined using high redshift SNe, which is equivalent to fixing your cosmological model. If you change $q_0$, then $H_0$ changes. This is discussed by Riess in section 4.3, directly in terms of changing $\Omega_M$ etc. The effect on $H_0$ is small because the mean redshift of the sample is only 0.07.

Comment: @RobJeffries, I don't see a major in-congruence between your comment and my statement. "In case I don't see ya, good afternoon, good evening and goodnight.", oh, good morning too. Which continent are you from? I am curious.

Answer (score 2):

Supernovae observations at low redshifts can yield a value for $H_0$ that is insensitive to other cosmological parameters and independent of other methods. That isn't the case for the other main cosmological parameters, where joint constraints from multiple methods (including the CMB, baryon acoustic oscillations) are needed to get them with any precision.

Some very recent results can be found in the summary provided on behalf of the Dark Energy Survey (DES) by [Abbott et al. (2019)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.02374), which also contains many references to other sources of data.

"Supernova cosmology" works by comparing the apparent magnitude of Type Ia supernovae, which depends on their luminosity distance, with their redshift. The former depends on the present-day value of the Hubble parameter, but also on its history with redshift, and hence has some sensitivity to the cosmological parameters.

The important equations are that the luminosity distance is given by
$$d_L = c(1+z)\int_0^{z} \frac{dz'}{H(z')},$$
where the Hubble parameter depends on redshift as
$$ H(z) = H_0 \left[ \Omega_M (1+z)^3 + \Omega_\Lambda (1+z)^{-3(1+w)}\right]^{-1/3}\ .$$

In the latter equation, $w$ is the equation of state parameter for dark energy. If we are dealing with a cosmological constant then $w=-1$. The above equations *assume* a flat universe and the results are sensitive to both $\Omega_M$ and $\Omega_\Lambda$.

More general formulations are also possible where flatness is not assumed and what is found is a degeneracy between $\Omega_M$ and $\Omega_\Lambda$. i.e. Supernovae observations alone do not yield both parameters simultaneously, they are most sensitive to the combination $\Omega_\Lambda - \Omega_M$.  A typical plot of results is shown below (this one from the Supernova Cosmology Project, but all other surveys have produced plots with similar morphology).

[image: Concordance plot]

These plots, sometimes called "concordance plots" show that the cosmological parameters are actually given by simultaneous constraints by multiple cosmological observations. So whilst the CMB results alone strongly favour a flat universe, the supernova observations suggest that in order to be flat there must be some form of dark energy.

To get to your question. Observations of supernovae do not independently yield any cosmological parameters (with any precision) *apart* from $H_0$. The constraint on $H_0$ is obtained from the supernovae that are observed at low redshift, that sample the expansion that is in the local universe, but which are far enough away to be in the "Hubble flow". At low redshifts ($z<0.1$) then $H(z) \simeq H_0$, with only small corrections that depend on the cosmological parameters.

Determining the other cosmological parameters depends on combining the supernova results with other constraints, so it isn't possible to talk about tensions between results from supernovae Vs results with other methods.