# Is there a standard distance/z data set for cosmology given new measurements?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, data

I've seen this data set in a few places.

[image]

Found here: https://lco.global/spacebook/light/redshift/

Do the measurements from SH0ES and Planck that cause the Hubble tension alter this table?

I can find the `H_0` from each of this studies, and I can assume the Planck measurement applies to a range of > 13 billion years, but what range does SH0ES apply to, and how does each affect the `z`column?

---

I came back to edit this to provide the chart I made using WolframAlpha. Full list of data and sources here:

https://mikehelland.github.io/hubbles-law/notes/zdata_full

Units are billion years and billion light years.

```
z       [H=74 lookback     co-distance]   [H=67.4 lookback    co-distance]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1              7.4        10.4                    8.1        11.4 
 2              9.8        16.4                   10.8        18.0 
 3             11.0        20.1                   12.1        22.1 
 4             11.6        22.8                   12.7        25.0 
 5             11.9        24.7                   13.1        27.1 
 6             12.2        26.2                   13.4        28.8 
 7             12.3        27.5                   13.5        30.2 
 8             12.4        28.5                   13.7        31.3 
 9             12.5        29.4                   13.8        32.2 
10             12.6        30.1                   13.8        33.0 
11             12.7        30.7                   13.9        33.8 
12             12.7        31.3                   14.0        34.4 
13             12.7        31.8                   14.0        34.9 
14             12.8        32.3                   14.0        35.4 
15             12.8        32.7                   14.1        35.9 
16             12.8        33.1                   14.1        36.3 
17             12.8        33.4                   14.1        36.7 
18             12.9        33.7                   14.1        37.0 
19             12.9        34.0                   14.1        37.4 
20             12.9        34.3                   14.2        37.7 
21             12.9        34.6                   14.2        37.9 
22             12.9        34.8                   14.2        38.2 
23             12.9        35.0                   14.2        38.4 
24             12.9        35.2                   14.2        38.7 
25             12.9        35.4                   14.2        38.9
```

Comment: For Hubble tension, see answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/532236/hubble-tension-and-density-parameter/532337#532337

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do the measurements from SH0ES and Planck cause the Hubble tension to alter this table?

No, it does not. The problem with the $H_0$ tension is most likely due to the $\Lambda$CDM model (e.g., we need an another model)

The Hubble tension is about the disagreement in the value of the $H_0$. If you try to measure the Planck constant at the moon in the far future or in the past and in Neptune or any other place, it should give you the same answer. Because it is a constant. Similarly the early and late universe Hubble constant measurements should agree with each other but they do not. There are a couple of cosmological parameters in the $\Lambda$CDM model such as $\Omega_mh^2$,  $\Omega_bh^2$, and $\theta_*$, which can be precisely determined from the CMB measurements. These measurements allow us to calculate the $H_0$ for the $\Lambda$CDM model. **Remember that different models give different $H_0$ results.**

When you consider the $\Lambda$CDM model you'll obtain $H_0\approx 67.6$ but when we measure $H_0$ locally we obtain $H_0 \approx 74$.

The local measurements do not use any cosmological model to obtain $H_0$ (At least they are trying to). For instance, the SH$0$ES uses a technique called local distance ladder to measure the $H_0$. In this method, they are observing the SNIa's in the range of  $0.0233<z <0.15$.

In this case, we know that $z$ will not change since there is no change in the equations if you are still considering the $\Lambda$CDM model.

Comment: Hi @Layla . You obviously know a great deal more about this subject than I do. Consequently what I have deduced from my reading is likely to be wrong. I would much appreciate your insight about the following. The $H_0$ tension seems to be based on two different data sets used to fit a "best" model. (1) astronomical data using the standard candle based on super novae. (2) variations in the CMB pattern. Either or both may have flaws not yet investigated.

Comment: @Buzz People are searching for it but it seems that the problem is not due to a systematic error, but due to our cosmological model (i.e., $\Lambda$CDM is wrong/incomplete etc.). Over the years there have been done many observations to obtain $H_0$ locally and most of them give higher $H_0$ (Only TRGB gives lower $H_0$ values which is interesting).

Comment: We cannot directly measure $H_0$ from CMB. We have to decide on a model and then make calculations under that model to obtain $H_0$. So, obtaining $H_0$ from CMB is different than the local measurements. In local measurements we are not using any cosmological model, but purely observational data.

Comment: Hi @Layla . "We cannot directly measure H0 from CMB." I did not understand that CMB data led to any ΛCDM type model. I thought is was more like a local perturbation type of statistical model.

Comment: @Buzz I did not understand your question..

Comment: Hi @Layla . I understood what you are saying is that (1) a ΛCDM model is used to calculate Ho from CMB data, and (2) that another ΛCDM model is used to calculate Ho from astronomical data involving the behavior of supernovae. If I misunderstood your comment I apologize. From another source I thought regarding (1) that no ΛCDM model is used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116567/discussion-between-buzz-and-layla).